# Font disturbtion on css transition

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, css-transitions

I use CSS3 transition for hover effect on products, a tag comes up from bottom over product image :

While the tag is coming up and after it comes up for about 0.5 second, the font is not smooth and clear, but about 0.5 ~ 1 second after transition finishes, it becomes clear and smooth. this problem occurs with Firefox.
with Chrome and IE it is negligible .

[image]

Is there any solution for this problem?

UPDATE:

```css
.product-hover {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
 
}
.product-hover:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .4s;
}
.product-hover a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #ff0022;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: .4s;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.product-hover a:hover {
  background: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #444;
}
.product-carousel-price ins {
  color: #ff0022;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.product-hover a i.fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.product-hover a.add-to-cart-link {
  top: -25%;
  display: none;
}
.product-hover a.view-details-link {
  bottom: -25%;
}
.single-product h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.single-product h2 a {
  color: #222;
}
.single-product p {
  color: #ff0022;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.single-product {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.single-product:hover {} .single-product:hover .product-hover a.add-to-cart-link {
  top: 25%;
}
.single-product:hover .product-hover a.view-details-link {
  bottom: 40%;
}
.single-product:hover .product-hover:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-product">
  <div class="product-f-image">
    <img src="images/products/product-3.jpg" />
    <div class="product-hover">
      <a href="single-product.html" class="view-details-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>مشاهده محصول</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2><a href="single-product.html">New Bag</a></h2>
  <div class="product-carousel-price">
    <ins>$400.00</ins>  <del>$425.00</del>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide html/markup that resproduces this issue. (I can read code, not pictures)

Comment: Please write the chunk in JS fiddle

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898499/css3-animation-issue-font-rendering

Comment: Each browser renders fonts differently. Firefox has always rendered fonts heavier than chrome. My guess is it's just a bug in the transition and something that you really won't be able to control. But without seeing your code, it's impossible to know. Hard to fix code from a jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the bug you mention in my setup (Firefox 40.0a2 and Chrome 41.0, Linux). I see it as bold and smooth throughout the animation as in your "after completion" image.

One thing you could try, is to make the text manually bolder and apply an imperceptible transformation, to see if you could at least force the text to always be in the "first state".

```
.view-details-linnk {
   transform: rotate(0.00001deg);
}
```

I applied this trick to other rendering quirks with CSS animations and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into one of the more annoying text render properties of Firefox. In order to speed up the transition animations, the font isn't rendered "fully", the render path is cut off prematurely, so the font will render differently before and after the transition, compared to during.

File an issue over on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org so that Mozilla gets to hear about it, and can either point you at where this bug is already being worked on, or can start tracking this issue off of your bug report.